# Please help me convert the comments on this question to "let us continue this discussion in chat"

Tags: support, comments, chat

Without the link that's provided after enough back-and-forth, it's not clear to me how to easily "continue this discussion in chat." Could someone help on [Don't heavier objects actually fall faster because they exert their own gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/1483)

It's clear the commenter I've been interacting with is looking for an education, and comments on the question are not the place to do that.

Comment: Usually there's an automatically generated comment from SE system that says something to the effect of asking you to move comments to chat after a few back & forth comments. I don't think it appears on the mobile app, however.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new), then leave a comment with a link to the room on the question.